# Printing String reverse

Tags: string, printing, reverse

I want to write a program, whne user enter "asdfg" program should be print "gfdsa" how can i do this? I have no idea about this.

```
String s;
String rev;

Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println ("Enter 's' String : ");
s = sc.next();

System.out.println ("reverse of " + s + " equal to " + rev);
```

Comment: You should first try something. How would you do it on paper? Transform that into code. This is a very basic problem, for which a lot of information is available with a simple web search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will work

```
        string input = "sample text";
        char[] outputArray = input.ToCharArray();           
        Array.Reverse(outputArray);
        Console.WriteLine(outputArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   System.out.println ("reverse of " + s + " equal to " + new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString());
```